# onPause not called when back button pressed?

Tags: android, back-button

It was my understanding, obviously wrong, that `onPause()` is called whenever the back button is pressed? Now in my code I've put this `onPause()` event:

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();        

    if(!_END_GAME){
        Builder _alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage("onPause, with game NOT over!");
        _alert.setNeutralButton("OK.",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                arg0.dismiss(); // Kills the interface
                System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
                finish();
            }
        });
        _alert.setTitle("Your Score!");
        _alert.show();
    }
```

}

Now the problem is, the dialog does not launch what-so-ever, and then the code errors out. I put the dialog there to try to visualize where the `onPause(`) was called and help me debug some other variables and such. Yet like I said it never even gets shown. Any ideas why this would be? Is there a function that is launched prior to `onPause()` when the back button is pressed? Thank you in advance for any info.

Comment: It's true: there situations where `onPause()` is not called when a Fragment is no longer visible!  I have the same problem, but a different situation.  It seems that the FragmentManager can still hold Fragments in memory.  When the user hits the Back button, that can supercede the FM, swapping the entire set of Fragments out and displaying a previous state.  This can miss all the onPause, onStop, and onDestroy methods for those Fragments.  --or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check for the back button by overriding `onKeyDown`, not testing in `onPause`. `onPause` gets called whenever your activity <strike>is no longer in the background</strike> leaves the foreground; it is not necessarily finishing. (You can check `isFinishing()` for that.) See [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html) for more info on handling the back key.

Comment: Don't check for the back button. That's a terrible hack and bound to break in many cases. There are countless other ways to bring the activity to the background (incoming phone call, home button, etc).

Comment: Thank you very much, I've started down this path and quickly realized where I was going wrong. Thanks for the speedy response though!.

Comment: @EboMike - why is checking for the back button a hack and bound to break in many cases? That's exactly the strategy that Dianne Hackborn recommends in the blog post I referenced. It's _much_ better than checking for such things during `onPause()`.

Comment: @Ted: Depends on what you want to do it for. If it's trying to intercept the app disappearing, there are countless of ways it can be circumvented (see my first comment for examples).

Comment: @EboMike - My understanding is that OP wants to deal specifically with the case of the user pressing the back button (and hence finishing the activity) before the game was over. Checking for the back button in `onKeyPressed` is the only way to distinguish between that case and the others you mentioned, so I don't understand the recommendation to _not_ check for the back button.

Comment: @Ted - Dianne's post is about *how* to capture the back key press.  It doesn't say one can depend on capturing the back key press to detect exiting the application.  As EboMike pointed out, there are many ways to exit an app.  Another obvious way is to press the home key.

Comment: @Thane - Pressing the home key does not exit the application. It pushes it into the background, but it is still there, in the state it was left after `onStop()` returned (unless the system decides it needs to kill the process). Inside `onPause()` and `onStop()`, `isFinishing()` will return _false_ if they are called because of a press of the  home key. When the application is launched again, it will return to the state in which it was left.

Comment: Right: "unless the system decides it needs to kill the process".  I no longer understand the point of this conversation.

Comment: @Thane - the point is that when an application **exits** because of the back button, then when it starts again it will be created in its initial state. The system calls `onCreate(null)`. When an application process is killed off because of low resources, when it starts again it is supposed to be (re)created in whatever state it was in when it was paused/stopped. The system calls `onCreate` with saved instance state data. If you want to prevent the first but not the second while a game is in progress, then checking for the back button is the only way. Being killed off and exiting are different.

Comment: @Ted
I've since used this:
`if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
      if(!_END_GAME){
       killAndReturnParams(0);
  }      
}`
This seems to work just fine for tidying up my activity with my custom function? Is there a more efficient method to do this, such as calling my function within either onPause(), or isFinishing()?

Comment: @While-E - if all you want to do is know when the user has pressed the back button so you can clean up (as opposed to preventing the user from exiting), then you can do that in `onPause()` and use `isFinishing()` to distinguish between exiting and, say, being interrupted by a phone call. Note that `isFinishing()` is not part of the activity lifecycle, so don't override that expecting it to be called by the system. What's inefficient about what you're doing now? If it ain't broke, ....

Answer (score 4):

`onPause` will always be called when your activity is no longer in the foreground, that's guaranteed. Maybe your `_END_GAME` is not false? Add a debug log output to your onPause method, you'll see that it always gets called.

I should note though that displaying a dialog during onPause is extremely bad form - the user is trying to get rid of your app (could even be because of an incoming phone call). You DO NOT want a dialog then. That goes against the Android design.

In fact, the Android OS will simply short-circuit your app if you try to do lengthy shenanigans in onDestroy or onPause. Basically, if those get called, you're supposed to disappear quietly.

If you really want to intercept the back button, you can check for the button like Ted suggested, but keep in mind that your app can go to the background in many other ways - home button, selected notification, incoming phone call, etc.

Comment: Yes, as stated I was simply debugging, wasn't going to have the dialog in end-use.

Answer (score 2):

`onPause` is getting called, and your dialog *is* showing, just for a tiny split-second before Android finishes your app. Put log statements in there if you want to watch what is going on.

If you want to show a dialog when the back button is pressed then the easiest way (works on Android 2.1+) is to override the `onBackPressed` method in your activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (gameRunning) {
        // show dialog
    } else {
        // exit
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```