# Timer not stopped when i click back button in android

Tags: android

I am using the countdown timer but when i click back button the timer continues.Can any body tell me how can i stop when i click my phone back button not my application back button.

Sorry for my English.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain more? What does your timer do? Perhaps if we understand your app some more we can give an answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about overriding [the `onBackPressed()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29)? Something like this (untested):

```
CountDownTimer mTimer;

// snip...

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mTimer.cancel();
}
```

Comment: He should probably cancel the timer whenever the activity goes into the background (e.g., pressing the home button), not just on the back button. The right place to do that is in `onPause` as @ohm suggests.

Comment: @Ted: The OP hasn't asked about a background scenario - more specifically a BACK button press which will finish the activity. It may be possible that a it is OK for a timer to continue whilst a user temporarily goes to the home screen but the timer must be stopped in a 'finish' scenario. Two different things.

Comment: @MisterSquonk - Yes, it's _possible_ that the timer should continue, but it's just as likely that OP would want it to stop whenever the activity is paused. That's why I said "probably". A common error to Android newcomers is thinking the back button is the only way for an activity to be paused. (OP's reference to an "application back button" suggests non-Android thinking.)

Comment: I need to do something similar. I need to start a timer once the back button is pressed.  I tried overriding the onBackPressed method and using a CountDownTimer but it doesn't start.. I want to start a timer once a dialog is dismissed.  The timer starts when I call startTimer() from resume button on dialog but nothing happens if I place the same method startTimer() in the onBackPressed() method.  anyone w/ ideas as to why?

Answer (score 2):

You need to cancel the timer. Call `timer.cancel()` when you press the back button. E.g. in the `onPause()` method.

Comment: I'm quite new to Android myself, but it seems like `onPause()` won't do what the OP wants: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572982/onpause-not-called-when-back-button-pressed. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Matt: Yes and no. Normally onPause() would suffice but actually the safest way is to check the timer exists (i.e., not null) and call cancel in onDestroy() as a last resort.

Comment: Actually main problem is that when i press my device back button then my timer does not stop.

Comment: thank you i used the onBackPressed  ()  method  it is working.